# Delphi code completion fail with anonymous methods

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Please create a new FMX application, add a button and a memo to run this example. I have this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTask.Run(procedure
            var
              client: TIdHTTP;
              result: string;
            begin
              client := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
              try
                try
                  client.ReadTimeout := 4000;
                  client.ConnectTimeout := 4000;
                  result := client.Get('a valid url here just as test');
                  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
                                           begin
                                             Memo1.Lines.Add(result);
                                           end);
                except
                  on E: Exception do
                    begin
                      TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
                                           begin
                                             Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
                                           end);
                    end
                end;
              finally
                client.Free;
              end;
            end);
end;
```

It works as I expect but the problem is in the IDE. If I place the cursor somewhere in the body of the anonymous function, I get the closing of the finally statement automatically.

How can I fix this?

---

First I am here

[image]

Then I press enter and I have this!

[image]

If you put the cursor at the beginning and not at the end of the line, you can add new spaces without the completion. How to solve this problem? Well, I have discovered that the issue happens because there is this code:

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
                         begin
                           Memo1.Lines.Add(result);
                         end);
```

If you remove this code, the issue doens't happen anymore. Is this a bug in the IDE?

Comment: I have a Delphi unit in which every Return causes an `end` to be inserted. (So, if I press Return five times, I get five `end`.) It is driving me crazy. I haven't seen this behaviour in previous Delphi versions.

Comment: I think that this is weird too, I see that Object Pascal Handbook by Marco Cantu suggests this pattern (the except inside), I think this is weird

Comment: Known issue: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18079

Comment: I swear I recall a similar (but not identical) question I asked about a year ago, but can't find it. Basically, in the same scenario, when a) spawning an anonymous thread, and b) calling synchronize, and c) pressing `enter` within that synchronization, it would continuously add `end;` for every `enter` pressed.

Comment: @JerryDodge I blame the internet connection I have where I am at present (Bali) :-)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Indeed, I put my prior comment before I saw yours. That does drive me crazy too. I copy a line break to the clipboard and paste it as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a bug in the IDE?

Yes, this is a bug in the IDE. Your code is syntactically valid.

> How can I fix this?

The best way to avoid this is to create your code and surround it with `try...except...` to handle any exception:

```
  try
    MyClass := TComponent.Create(Self);
    try

    finally
      MyClass.Free;
    end;
  except on E: Exception do
  end;
```

So your code will be:

```
  TTask.Run(procedure
            var
              client: TIdHTTP;
              result: string;
            begin
              try
                Client := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
                try
                  client.ReadTimeout := 4000;
                  client.ConnectTimeout := 4000;
                  result := client.Get('a valid url here just as test');
                  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
                                           begin
                                             Memo1.Lines.Add(result);
                                           end);
                finally
                  Client.Free;
                end;
              except on E: Exception do
                begin
                  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
                                           begin
                                             Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
                                           end);
                  end;
              end;
            end;
```

Comment: I thought that finally had to always enclose everything but it seems that the except goes out. Tried it and it worked!

Comment: @RosannaTrevisan Sure ;)

Comment: It still feels like an IDE bug to me. The OP's original code is perfectly syntactically valid.

Comment: Althogh, it will be a warning `[dcc32 Warning] UnitName.pas(37): W1036 Variable 'Client' might not have been initialized`

Comment: Probably the warning is about the fact that if the exception happens before `Client := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);`, the variable `Client` will never be used. But still, I think that this could be a bug!

Comment: Switching the finally and except blocks around is a work around and not a solution and it may not be something that everyone can get away with. A use case might need the objects freed in the finally block to still be valid in the exception. Something can still be a bug if occurs frequently.

Comment: @Andreas: To me too. It is an IDE bug. A pretty annoying bug too.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this a bug in the IDE?

Yes. This is a defect. Please submit a report to Quality Portal.